# Conditional deleting in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm using two sheets, one with the main values and reference datas.

The second sheet is for price calculation.

I use `=Filter` to get the values from sheet one where `Sheet1!E2:E <> 1`.

How can I get the row from Sheet2 deleted when the value is no longer inside the Filter Condition?

Answer (score 5):

Spreadsheet functions cannot delete rows. You need a script for this ([introduction to Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/)). The following function deletes any rows in Sheet2 where the entry in column E is less than 1 or greater than 9.

```
function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (data[i][4] < 1 || data[i][4] > 9) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Notes

- The indices of array `data` begin with 0; row and column numbers begin with 1. This is why there is  `i + 1` in the line with row deletion.
- The number 4 in `data[i][4]` corresponds to E, because 0,1,2,3,4... are A,B,C,D,E,...
- The rows are deleted from bottom up, so that deletion does not move the rows that are yet to be processed.